# Pandas.Dataframe select maximum value on 1 column with another criteria on other column.

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df_group1 as follows

```
     Node   Load  FX\n(kN)  FY\n(kN) FZ\n(kN)  MX\n(kN*m)  MY\n(kN*m)
0      1   SLU_1  -28.5908  -6.19009  609.036   46.742822 -186.668087
2      3   SLU_2  -52.7285  -6.19101  805.478   46.751259 -269.103795
4      5   SLU_3  -48.9524  -6.19284  634.366   46.768148 -186.232878
5      6   SLE_4  -6.79594  -10.0551  797.148   72.094493  -82.793428
6      7   SLE_1  -41.1434   -6.1956  817.653   46.793519 -218.747276
16     1   SLV_2  -7.72079  -17.6635  605.985  130.651786 -105.285847
18     3   SLV_3  -10.9175  -14.6851  808.529  124.897285 -108.000190
```

i need to to get whole row with the maximum value on *FZ\n(kN)* for rows containing only *SLU* in Load column.

I am trying to combine the two criteria as follows, but get an arrow:

```
df_group1_SLU = df_group1.loc[(df_group1['Load'].str.contains('SLU')) & (df_group1['FZ\n(kN)'].astype(float).idxmax())]
```

but it gives me the dataframe with only all rows containng SLU in Load column.
what am I doing wrong? Why idxmax conditions does not work?

thanks,
BR,
Aldar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[[df.loc[df['Load'].str.contains('SLU'), 'FZ\n(kN)'].idxmax()]]
```

[output]

```
   id  Node   Load  FX\n(kN)  FY\n(kN)  FZ\n(kN)  MX\n(kN*m)  MY\n(kN*m)
1   2     3  SLU_2  -52.7285  -6.19101   805.478   46.751259 -269.103795
```

Comment: it worked! not fully understood why, but thank you. what if i need to find maximum absolute value? df.loc[[df.loc[df['Load'].str.contains('SLU'), 'FZ\n(kN)'].abs().idxmax()]] is correct?

Comment: @AldarBudayev Yeh, that'll do it